# Objective-c - validate filled fields before publish item

Tags: ios, objective-c

In my application I send data to server and parse.
But I have to send image and you need to choose category.
When you don't choose category I show for user information.

But: how can I check if the user has filled in all the fields? In my app choose image and category?

This is my code with show error when you don't choose category and send action:

```
- (IBAction)submitItem:(UIButton *)sender {

    if ([category isEqualToString:@""]) {

        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Category 'All' is reserved" message:@"You need to choose different category" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
        [alert show];
        return;
    }

    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageView.image, 1.0);

    ///// send image to server

    NSString *urlString = urlSaveFullImageToServer;
```

Comment: What's your question?

Answer (score 0):

Your change could be as simple as using an else statement...

```
- (IBAction)submitItem:(UIButton *)sender {

    if ([category isEqualToString:@""]) {

        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Category 'All' is reserved" message:@"You need to choose different category" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
        [alert show];
        return;
    }
    else {

        NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageView.image, 1.0);

        ///// send image to server

        NSString *urlString = urlSaveFullImageToServer;

    ...
```

Personally I think a better approach is not to enable the "send" button until all of the data is complete.

Set the submit button `enabled` property to `NO` and then when the various pieces of information are entered (the image, the category) check to see if everything is complete - once it is, set `enabled` to `YES`